# How to relocate boxer dog from Europe (Belgrade,Serbia) to US (Atlanta, Georgia)?

Tags: usa, lufthansa, pets

I might be moving to US Atlanta Georgia with my boxer dog. I am trying to prepare and learn the risks as she will have to travel in the cargo area. Found some articles about Lufthansa being one of most caring companies, but I was hoping to hear experiences, positive or negative, if this can be done?

Comment: I don't know your sources but based on 2 intercontinental LH moves [Europe-Asia] both with 2 dogs [one in cargo; she has a "long nose", though], strongly recommend LH [I have no other relationship with LH than being their customer. Made Stop-over in FRA just to get LH]. Maybe since LH is used to dogs, but [quote from my earlier comment on a similar question, about the dog in cargo]: "The cabin crew was professional about dog travel! On board before taxing they told me they checked the she was aboard. During the flight they frequently went to check that she was fine, and kept me up-to-date"

Comment: Please rephrase and repost your question. 1) It belongs on [expatriates.se]. 2) Do not ask for *experiences, positive or negative*. That is too broad and opinion based. What is the *specific question* that you have that is not already answered in the *some articles about Lufthansa*?

Answer (score 1):

I can’t comment on the service but I can confirm that dogs weighing more than 8 KG including the transport container can be transported in the cargo hold under certain conditions:

> Dogs and cats that weigh more than 8 kg including their transport container, as well as hares and rabbits, may be transported under certain conditions as excess baggage in the aircraft’s air-conditioned cargo hold.

([Source](https://www.lufthansa.com/us/en/travelling-with-animals))